# Retag request: [caesar3] -> [caesar-3]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

I tried to retag [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/282520/housing-steps-and-requirements-in-caesar-3) but it wouldn't let me.

Comment: Robotnik was on the ball again. Looks like it is all done now.

Comment: Yup, all done. Sorry, forgot to update this post